# Powerscript manipulating IE on Windows Server 2008

Tags: silverlight, powershell, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to run my Silverlight tests via a command line (eventually MSBuild) working from [this example](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2292).

It all works fine on my XP Box but on Build Machine (Windows Server 2008) the IE window opens, then a second window opens with the Silverlight page in it. That page then shows the "Download Silverlight" picture and link. If I copy the URL from that page to a new IE window the page runs fine (no download icon, tests run).

I also tried the code from [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337896.aspx) , but get a similar issue - IE opens, then page under test opens in separate window.

Anyone got this working in Win2008? Any pointers?

Edit: chadwickmiller suggesst this is a UAC problem - any advice on how to get around this?

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When moving from trusted to non-trusted Vista/2008 will always open in a new window. This could be what is going on. You might be able to turn off UAC to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like the culprit. Is there a way to turn off UAC for just this? I don;t think the admins will go for turning it off all together.

Comment: I think you can use the Shell.Application COM object to get a reference to the new window, and then go on from there.

Answer (score 0):

So chadwickmiller got me moving in the right direction. To stop the second window opening I added the test site to my Trusted Sites in IE.

For the reason why (and a solution to) the "Download Silverlight" link was showing [see this Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264683/showing-silverlight-app-in-browser-from-batch-file-on-win2008/1274179#1274179).